# Which chest has the best loot?

Tags: guild-wars-2

In Guild Wars 2, you can find Grand, Magnificent, and Splendid Chests throughout the world, sometimes guarded by veterans or champions, sometimes at the end of jumping puzzles, and sometimes both!

Are there any differences between what each variety of chest rewards?

Comment: Good question, in my experience they all seem pretty equal. Mostly giving quite poor blue items, with a very occasional green or yellow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all chests with the same name are created equal, as each chest has specific items that it can drop. That being said, the general hierarchy from best to worst is:

1. World boss chest ([Frost Chest](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Frost_Chest), [Dragon Chest](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Dragon_Chest), [Ancient Treasure](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Ancient_Treasure), etc)
2. [Glorious Chest](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Glorious_Chest)
3. [Splendid Chest](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Splendid_Chest)
4. [Magnificent Chest](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Magnificent_Chest)
5. [Grand Chest](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Grand_Chest)

While chests named "Chest" have very mixed values.